# fetch an image from mongodb using gridfs and php

Tags: mongodb, gridfs

--
Earlier I stored an image to mongodb using the gridFS and I used the code below retrieve the image. However, it displayed me a bunch of characters rather than the real image. How should I correct this problem.

Thanks

`$m = new MongoClient();`
`$db = $m->test;`
`$gridFS = $db->getGridFS();`

`$id = 123;`

`echo $gridFS->findOne(array("_id" => $id))->getBytes();`

---

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use instead of gtbyte()

```
GridFS gfsPhoto = new GridFS(mongoTemplate.getDb(), "photo");
GridFSDBFile image = gfsPhoto.findOne(new ObjectId(id));
InputStream stream = image.getInputStream();
```